# Regular expression to match some conditions given a formatted file name?

Tags: ruby, regex

(Sorry for the bad title, any suggestion appreciated) ;-)

Well, consider those strings:

```
first = "SC/SCO_160ZA206_T_mlaz_kdiz_nziizjeij.ext"
second = "MLA/SA2_jkj15PO_B_lkazkl lakzlk-akzl.oxt"
third = "A12A/AZD_KZALKZL_F_LKAZ_AZ__azaz___.ixt"
```

I'm looking for a regular expression allowing me to get arrays like this (in ruby):

```
first_array = ['SCO', '160ZA206', 'T', 'mlaz_kdiz_nziizjeij']
second_array = ['SA2', 'jkj15PO', 'B', 'lkazkl lakzlk-akzl']
third_array = ['AZD', 'KZALKZL', 'F', 'LKAZ_AZ__azaz___']
```

The first match must be anything right after the `/` and before the first `_`

The second match must be anything between the first and the second `_`

The third match must be anything between the second and the third `_`

The last match must be anything between the third `_` and the last `.`

I can't get it: `[^\/].?([A-Z]*)_(.*)_(.*)[\.$]` :-(

Comment: Does ruby have a scope limited `split` function? If yes, take the substring from right after the first / to the end, and then split against `_`, with three groups maximum: the "array" elements (if that is what is called in ruby) will contain what you want.

Comment: +1 It's nice seeing a regex question where the OP put in some effort before contracting out to stackoverflow

Comment: @fge: unfortunately I can't split my string using `'_'`, the last match could contain `'_'`.

Comment: @ean5533: Thx to Rubular.com :-)

Comment: @Fro_oo which is why I said to _limit the split to three groups_!

Comment: @fge I demonstrated your suggestion.

Comment: @fge: sorry, you're right, this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're super close. Just add a question mark to the second matcher to make it lazy (otherwise, it won't stop at the first underscore), and then duplicate that matcher.

```
[^\/].?([A-Z]*)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)[\.$]
```

Comment: Nice! Thx for your answer, the correct regexp is `[^\/].?([A-Z]*)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)[\.$]` (I need 4 matches)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @fge's split suggestion:

```
str = "SC/SCO_160ZA206_T_mlaz_kdiz_nziizjeij.ext"
p str[(str.index('/')+1)...str.rindex('.')].split( '_', 4)
#=> ["SCO", "160ZA206", "T", "mlaz_kdiz_nziizjeij"]
```

It splits on _ for max 4 elements (the fourth element is the remainder).

Comment: I don't think he wants the `.ext`, `.oxt`, etc.

Comment: Nice implementation but as Dylan Markow pointed out, the extension must be removed.

Comment: `File.basename` can also get rid of the extension IIRC.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm Yes, true. Had another look and changed it to `rindex('.')` , which should be good enough if the end of the string is guaranteed to be a file with an extension (and for the fun of using `rindex`).